# Prove that G is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If in a finite group G an element $a$ has exactly two conjugates, prove that G has a normal subgroup $N \ne e$.

I know to find the number of conjugates of $a$ I can use the formula $\frac{|G|}{|N(a)|} = c_a$ where $N(a)$ is the normalizer thus $\frac{|G|}{|N(a)|} = c_a = 2$ but how can I show that G is not simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. We know that $N(a) \leq G$ ($N(a)$ is a subgroup of $G$). Further, since we are working in a finite group, the index of the subgroup is given by $$|G:N(a)| = \frac{|G|}{|N(a)|}$$ which you correctly claim is 2. We know that any subgroup of index 2 is a normal one. So in particular we have that $N(a) \triangleleft G$.

To see that any subgroup $H$ of index 2 in a group $G$ is normal, note that there are only two cosets, $H$ and $G-H$. Of course $1H = H1$ because the identity commutes. But also, if we choose some $g\notin H$, then $gH = G-H$. But at the same time, the right cosets also partition $G$ so $Hg = G-H$ and thus $gH = Hg$ so $H$ must be normal.

Answer (score 4):

Any subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Comment: Why would this have index 2?

Comment: @user104235 You just write it in your question!

Comment: @user Maybe I am confused. But the conjugacy class is the same as the index?

Comment: @user104235 No, but the number of elements in a conjugacy class is the index of centralizer.

Comment: @user That is a very important note that I should rmbr! Thanks a million for clearing that up!!